# How do I grab the headline titles from the Google News webpage with Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, google-news

I saved an offline file of https://news.google.com/search?q=amazon&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen

Having trouble determining how to grab the titles of the listed articles.

```
import scrapy

class newsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "news"
    start_urls = ['file:///127.0.0.1/home/toni/Desktop/crawldeez/googlenewsoffline.html/'
                  ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for xrnccd in response.css('a.MQsxIb.xTewfe.R7GTQ.keNKEd.j7vNaf.Cc0Z5d.EjqUne'):
            yield {
                'ipQwMb.ekueJc.RD0gLb': xrnccd.css('h3.ipQwMb.ekueJc.RD0gLb::ipQwMb.ekueJc.RD0gLb').get(),
            }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the troubles you are experiencing? Does you code produce any error messages? Is so, share them. Or does it run but produces unexpected results? If so, give us an idea what is the expected and actual output.

Comment: I run ‘scrapy crawl spidername -o filename.csv’ in the terminal to save the text from the webpage to a CSV file. The file is made (and works with the quote example on the scrapy site), however nothing gets saved to the file. There are no errors. I’m assuming I’m trying to grab the wrong items from the webpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to lay in the fact that the page content is rendered dynamically using JavaScript and thus can't be extracted from the HTML using `css` or `xpath` methods. However, it's present in the response body, so you can extract it using regular expressions. Here's the [Scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) session to show how:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://news.google.com/search?q=amazon&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen"
...
>>> import re
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> titles = re.findall(r'<h3 class="[^"]+?"><a[^>]+?>(.+?)</a>', response.text)
>>> pprint(titles)
['Amazon will no longer sell Chinese goods in China',
 'YouTube is finally coming back to Amazon’s Fire TV devices',
 'Amazon Plans to Use Digital Media to Expand Its Advertising Business',
 'Amazon flooded with fake reviews; Learn how to spot them',
 'How To Win in Today&#39;s Amazon World',
 'Amazon Day: How to schedule Amazon deliveries',
 'Bezos Disputes Amazon’s Market Power. But His Merchants Feel the Pinch',
 '20 Best Action Movies to Stream on Amazon Prime',
 ...]
```

Comment: @user5451844 Consider accepting the answer then to close the question.